# jQuery plugin unique timer on each instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, timeout

I've built a jQuery plugin that detects window resize to change two div colours from red to blue. It then uses a timer event to detect when the window finishes resizing and change the colour back from blue to red.

The problem is that only one of the two divs turn back to red. I think this may be due to sharing the same timer variable.

How do I scope the timer event so it is unique to each instance?

http://jsfiddle.net/hqN2k/9/

```
!function($){
$.fn.resizeD = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
 $(window).resize(function() {              
     $this.css("background","blue");

     var existingResizeTimeout = $(this).data("resize_timer");

     if(existingResizeTimeout){
         clearTimeout(existingResizeTimeout);
     }

     $.data(this, 'resize_timer', setTimeout(function() {

         $this.css("background","red");

     }, 500));
});
});
}
}(window.jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".test").resizeD();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$.data(this, 'resize_timer', setTimeout(function() {
     $this.css("background","red");
}, 500));
```

To

```
$.data($this, 'resize_timer', setTimeout(function() {
     $this.css("background","red");
}, 500));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hqN2k/10/